# c# log to file that is used by another logger

Tags: c#, logging, synchronization

I'm trying to write logs to the log file that is currently being used by logger from another process (this second logger is written in C using following:

```
::CreateFile(m_fileName.c_str(), GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE|FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, CREATE_NEW, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL ); 
::WriteFile(handle(handle), s.data(), (DWORD)s.size(), &written, NULL) 
::FlushFileBuffers(handle(handle))
```

and is never closed).
My custom logger also needs to write to the same log file. Is there any way I can achieve that in C# using synchronization techniques such as locks? Currently I'm opening file using:

```
File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

and able to write some information to the log, but it appears in the random place in the middle of previous occurrence, so that log becomes a mess.

Comment: Is `FileMode.Append` any different?

Answer (score 1):

As you have noticed you can open and write to the same file from multiple processes. The output is of course interleaved randomly.

Single writes are atomic in the sense that the bytes of a single write will appear contiguously, so it would be enough to make sure that each log item is written in a single write operation. Note, that FileStream does internal buffering. You need to disable that by setting the buffer size to `1` (the minimum).

If you can't or don't want to ensure that you need to synchronize. Cross-process synchronization is easy to achieve using a named mutex.